Failed to load API definition. Errors Hide Fetch error Internal Server Error /openapi.json
I am new to working with FastApi. I am trying to write my first program for requesting a data model.I keep encountering a problem when i write  /docs after the address.
This is my code
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Course(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: int
    author: Optional[str] = None

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/courses/")
def create_course(course: Course):
    return course


I run it using
python -m uvicorn main1:app --reload

I was expecting to see a request body

I don't think you can receive a Course object as an API parameter. The API can receive a course name, and then query the model to find the Course with that name.

The Python console should show an error message - the code you've included does not generate any errors by itself as long as you're starting it properly with unicorn. And it's perfectly fine to have a pydantic model as an endpoint parameter; that means FastAPI will expect a JSON body that can be de-serialized to the model.
